Getting /home/ubuntu/NAS: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member' - Accessing files on a synology NAS drive
I'm trying to follow this https://kb.synology.com/en-uk/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC#x_anchor_encryptedvolume
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install -y mdadm lvm2
mdadm -AsfR && vgchange -ay
      mdadm: Found some drive for an array that is already active: /dev/md/brayc:2
      mdadm: giving up.
      mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md127 : active raid1 sdb3[1]
      3902196544 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
lvs
mount /dev/md127 /home/ubuntu/nas
mount: /home/ubuntu/nas: uknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call

But I have problems when I run the mount command

You are using LVM so on top of your RAID array is a LVM physical volume which you cannot mount, you need to mount the LVM logical volume (LV). Use lvs to find the name of the volume (or lsblk) and then mount the logical volume with mount /dev/<vgname>/<lvname> /home/ubuntu/nas.
Your lvs output will look like this:
$ sudo lvs
  LV   VG          Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home fedora -wi-ao---- 822,66g                                                    
  root fedoraa -wi-ao---- <69,99g

first column is your LV name, second your VG name. So with my setup I'd be using /dev/fedora/home to mount my home LV.
